# Unable to send response using app.use in node js

Tags: node.js, express

code is used to set up server and calling a html page

```
const express =require('express')
const path=require('path')
const app=express()
const ppath=path.join(__dirname,'../public/index.htm')
app.use(express.static(ppath))
app.listen(3000,()=>
{**strong text**
    console.log("HEy")
})
```

Comment: Please make the question clearer, include any errors or expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.htm'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `express.static()` a directory and it looks for requested files in that directory.  You don't pass `express.static()` a path to a single file.  That will not work.

If you actually want other static files in the same directory to be served, you could point `express.static()` at the parent directory.

Of, if you just want that one file served, then you just set up a route for that one file:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public/index.htm'));
});
```

For an further help with `express.static()`, we also need to know exactly what the incoming URL is that you want to serve `index.htm` with.